# Data Transformation with many 0 and 1

Tags: data-transformation

[image]I'd like to transform my data (many 0 and 1) to reach normal Distribution. Is there a way to transform the following Distribution?

[image]

Comment: I don't think so. Why do you think you need to do that?!

Comment: I did run a linear mixed effects model (lmer). The model assumption homoscedacity seems to be violated. What do you mean?

Comment: well, it is not so rare that people believe that they need normally distributed data when in fact that is not essential, and/or solutions for nonnormal data are available

Comment: your variable name is "percent activity".  Do you know the denominators these are calculated from, e.g. if "100% activity" in one case is "active in 10 out of 10 cases", or are these strictly proportion data?  In other words, can you run a binomial GLMM with `glmer` instead?  Alternatively, you can try beta regression (see the `glmmADMB` package), but in that case you will still have to do something to deal with your 0/1 values ...

Comment: but linear mixed model would be more nice instead of gamm or glmm... but model assumption seems to be violated, no? is there no way to handle linearity in homoscedacity (Picture above)?

Comment: thanks for comments! 100% activity means: 12 active cases out of 12, activity measured in 5 min intervals... maybe I'll try a glmer or beta Regression...